# Check if Row is already exist in table before inserting

Tags: vb.net, loops, validation

Well its been a while since my last post about saving loops through checkboxlist.
So I did manage to check the input before it saved into table, but somehow it couldnt save any data even if wasnt duplicate one.
Wanted to create a function to check if each checkboxlist is already present within the table but I cant manage it because it needs value from this script so I skip it.

```
Using conn2 As New SqlConnection()
        conn2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
            .ConnectionStrings("BackboneConnectionString").ConnectionString()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into EL_MstFunctionalNilai values(@IDFunc, @nik, @IDFuncParent, @IDFuncChild, @IDFuncMtr, '', '', '0')"
            cmd.Connection = conn2
            conn2.Open()
            For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList2.Items
                If item.Selected Then
                    'cmd.Parameters.Clear()

                    Dim urutan As Int32 = GetNumberFunctional()
                    Dim str As String = item.Value.ToString

                    Dim strArr() As String = str.Split("_")
                    Dim IDFunctionalParent1 As String = strArr(0)
                    Dim IDFunctionalChild1 As String = strArr(1)
                    Dim IDFunctionalMtr1 As String = strArr(2)

                    cmd.CommandText = "select count(*)as numrows from el_mstFunctionalnilai where nik = @nik and idfuncmtr = @IDFuncMtr"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nik", txtnik.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncMtr", IDFunctionalMtr1)
                    queryresult = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

                    If queryresult = 0 Then

                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFunc", urutan)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nik", txtnik.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncMtr", IDFunctionalMtr1) 'mtr
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncParent", IDFunctionalParent1) 'parent 
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncChild", IDFunctionalChild1) 'child

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        'Label1.Text = queryresult --> already check if queryresult has value

                    End If
                End If
            Next
            conn2.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

When its executed no error tho, so I cant figure it out what Im missing. Well how do I fix this up?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code in the debugger? If not, that is the next step. If you have, exactly where and how does what actually happens differ from your expectation?

Comment: debugging? not yet

Comment: You really need to have debugged your code before posting here. Unfortunately, many beginner tutorials and even paid courses neglect what is an essential skill. If you don't know how, you should learn now. Many errors are completely obvious when debugging because you can see exactly what value every variable and expression has at every step, so you can immediately see if a value is wrong or execution takes an unexpected path.

Answer (score 0):

```
el_mstFunctionalnilai

EL_MstFunctionalNilai
```

Which is it? Be careful about capitalization.

I have guessed at all the SqlDbType Please check your database to get the actual types.

Code following your pattern with 2 hits to database.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim queryResult As Integer
    'Pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection
    Using conn2 As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BackboneConnectionString").ConnectionString())
        'Pass the command text and the connection directly to the command constructor
        'You do not need as alias for Count
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select count(*) from EL_MstFunctionalNilai where nik = @nik and idfuncmtr = @IDFuncMtr", conn2)
            conn2.Open()
            'This value does not appear to change in the loop so I moved it outside the loop
            Dim urutan As Int32 = GetNumberFunctional()
            'Add the parameters outside of the loop and only change the value inside the loop
            'The value of the text box can't change inside the loop so it can be assigned outside the loop
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nick", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtnik.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDFuncMtr", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Insert into EL_MstFunctionalNilai values(@IDFunc, @nik, @IDFuncParent, @IDFuncChild, @IDFuncMtr, '', '', '0')", conn2)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@IDFunc", SqlDbType.Int).Value = urutan
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@nik", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtnik.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@IDFuncMtr", SqlDbType.VarChar) 'mtr
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@IDFuncParent", SqlDbType.VarChar) 'parent 
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@IDFuncChild", SqlDbType.VarChar) 'child
                For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList2.Items
                    If item.Selected Then
                        Dim str As String = item.Value.ToString
                        Dim strArr() As String = str.Split("_"c)
                        Dim IDFunctionalParent1 As String = strArr(0)
                        Dim IDFunctionalChild1 As String = strArr(1)
                        Dim IDFunctionalMtr1 As String = strArr(2)
                        cmd.Parameters("@IDFuncMtr").Value = IDFunctionalMtr1
                        queryResult = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
                        If queryResult = 0 Then
                            cmd2.Parameters("@IDFuncMtr").Value = IDFunctionalMtr1 'mtr
                            cmd2.Parameters("@IDFuncParent").Value = IDFunctionalParent1 'parent 
                            cmd2.Parameters("@IDFuncChild").Value = IDFunctionalChild1 'child
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I think it would be easier using one query that both checks for the existence of the record and inserts it if it doesn't exist.

```
Protected Sub Method2()
    Dim urutan As Int32 = GetNumberFunctional()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BackboneConnectionString").ConnectionString())
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("If Exists (Select 1 From EL_MstFunctionalNilai where nik = @nik and idfuncmtr = @IDFuncMtr) Select 0 Else Select 1 Insert into EL_MstFunctionalNilai values(@IDFunc, @nik, @IDFuncParent, @IDFuncChild, @IDFuncMtr, '', '', '0');", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nik", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtnik.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDFuncMtr", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDFunc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = urutan
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDFuncParent", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDFuncChild", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            cn.Open()
            For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList2.Items
                If item.Selected Then
                    Dim strArr() As String = item.Value.ToString.Split("_"c)
                    cmd.Parameters("@IDFuncMtr").Value = strArr(2)
                    cmd.Parameters("@IDFuncParent").Value = strArr(0)
                    cmd.Parameters("@IDFuncChild").Value = strArr(1)
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Well I already fixed this using Stored Procedure IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EL_MstFunctionalNilai WHERE nik = (@)nik and IDFuncMtr = (@)IDFuncMtr ) < 1 then insert. Totally easier with this way.
Cheers